# Web system development on Google's infrastructure or platform

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I've developed a few web systems on Google App Engine. Now that Google compute Engine is available, I couldn't help wondering which of the following is better, in terms of the information strategy of a company:

1. Google App Engine + webapp2 + ndb + Django templates + Python
2. Google Compute Engine + Linux + Django + MySQL + Python

I know this is a big question, which involves so many detailed thinkings, however, I would still like to hear how people think about it. I already has experience on #1, but #2 is appealing because there is no vendor lock-in.

Comment: As always, depends on your needs. Your q will probably get voted down since you are not asking a coding question How do you plan to scale that GCE? Thats why appengine exists.

Comment: You get infrastructure that scales for you with 1.  With 2, you have to handle that scaling yourself.  What happens when your MySQL server isn't performing well enough? You have to engineer that yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You not specify what you want to achieve/

1. Google App Engine + webapp2 + ndb + Django templates + Python

Designed for web, extreme scalability, pay per usage

1. Google Compute Engine + Linux + Django + MySQL + Python

Not designed for web but can be used, MySql is not high scalable, payer per usage.

Lock-in is not major problem if you want serve mass traffic - scalability and maintenance cost is more important. Both is some lock-in and choose not lock-in is also lock-in :)

Creating scalable platform on machines cost lost of time and effort and is what is done in PaaS in Google App Engine - this mean you can skip one phase of project. If you not plan really big traffic (near to facebook) maybe it is no sense to build servers farms on your own.

Comment: This answers most of my question. Thanks a million.